# Git stopped asking for password when signing commit

Tags: git, ubuntu, ubuntu-14.04

I set up git to allow GPG signing of commits. It was working fine but recently I've noticed that sometimes I am not prompted for a passphrase and I get the message `You need a passphrase to unlock the secret key for user:` when committing with the `-S` flag, although the commit still goes through. Other times I am prompted for the passphrase and everything works as usual.

The strange thing is that when I check `git log --show-signature` it shows that the commits that did not prompt for a passphrase are listed as having a good signature just like the others.

I'm running Ubuntu 14.04, git 1.9.1, and GnuPG 1.4.16.

I was thinking that it had something to do with how Ubuntu doesn't make enter your sudo passphrase if you have entered it recently. But I don't see how this would affect git.

Comment: Are you running [gpg-agent](http://superuser.com/questions/624343/keep-gnupg-credentials-cached-for-entire-user-session)?

Comment: No, I'm just running `git commit -S`

Comment: Yes. And if you have gpg-agent (that's from the `gnupg-agent` package) then it would explain your observed behavior.

Comment: I don't have gnupg-agent as far as I can tell. `gnupg-agent --version` returned `gnupg-agent: command not found`

Comment: The command is `gpg-agent --version`; I get (on my system) "gpg-agent (GnuPG) 2.0.22"

Comment: Oh, my mistake. I still don't have it though. `gpg-agent --version` returns `The program 'gpg-agent' is currently not installed.`

Comment: Gnome keyring implements a gpg agent. Do you have that?

Comment: Yes, It does appear that gnome keyring came pre-installed with 14.04. I guess it just works on it's own without any sort of setup?

Comment: Have you checked the settings in `~/.gnupg/gpg-agent.conf`?

Comment: `~/.gnupg/gpg-agent.conf` doesn't exist

Comment: How about `echo $GPG_AGENT_INFO`?

Comment: @ComputerDruid That outputs `/run/user/1000/keyring-1snE5N/gpg:0:1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your `GPG_AGENT_INFO` is set to `/run/user/1000/keyring-1snE5N/gpg:0:1`,
[gnome-keyring](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/GnomeKeyring) is acting as your GPG agent and is caching your passphrase, then using it to sign the future commits.

I believe gnome-keyring has a "lock keyring" option if you want it to stop providing keyring services for a while (which will then require you to unlock the keyring with your login password)

Comment: Just on a side note. Is there a reason git is giving the message `You need a passphrase to unlock the secret key` even though it is being fed the passphrase by gnome-keyring?